# Why the query takes forever when changing the value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance, sql-server-2012

If i have table `Mission` with the following structure :

```
emp_num              int             P.K
from_date            datetime        P.K
to_date              datetime        P.K
mission_location     varchar(200) 
mission_desc         varchar(200)
req_ser              int             P.K
req_year             int             P.K
```

---

```
CONSTRAINT [pkc_mission] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [emp_num] ASC,
    [from_date] ASC,
    [to_date] ASC,
    [ req_ser] ASC,
    [ req_year] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

---

When i try to run this query :

```
select *
from mission where emp_num =5307
```

it works very fast, but when i try to run the same query with another value, it takes forever !

```
select *
from mission where emp_num =4595
```

Comment: Check the execution plan could be parameter sniffing. The second query might still used the old execution plan. Try running this `select *
from mission where emp_num =4595 OPTION (RECOMPILE);`

Comment: Probably you run the first query and the result exists in the cache (while the new query isn't).

Comment: Perhaps employe 4595 has a zillion rows in the table and employee 5307 only has one.

Comment: In conclusion : Either it is stored in the cache, which means that the second execution is the correct one(you can test it by using the same query on different values you never selected before) , or that specific employee has a lot more records with value `4595` then with value `5307`

Comment: @GordonLinoff : ` employe 4595` has only 4 rows and the whole table about `20000` row

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare Could you rebuild the PK index?

Comment: @Prdp : I run the query through Management studio

Comment: @gotqn : How to do that

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare Is this a production database or local/test database?

Comment: @gotqn :it's a production database

Comment: Definitely sounds like parameter sniffing

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare How big is the table (count of rows and size)? Please run `exec sp_spaceused  'dbo.[mission]' `

Comment: Could you check your `index fragmentation` using the steps here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858.aspx#SSMSProcedureFrag

Comment: @gotqn `rows  reserved data      index_size unused
3628 712 KB 520 KB 24 KB 168 KB`

Comment: The table is pretty small, we are save to run this `ALTER INDEX [pkc_mission] ON [dbo].[Mission] REBUILD ` - this should rebuild the index and the statistics. After that execute your query again.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this -

```
select  *
from    mission with (forceseek)
where   emp_num = 4595
```

Comment: why `with (forceseek)` ?

Comment: First let see if the use of index improves the performance, If so, we can continue to investigate why the index is not being used.

Comment: I will suggest `with (forceseek)` only when I know my statistics are up to date

Comment: @Prdp, no dispute here. Investigation purposes only.